# Code quality question about handling multiple functions with same signature in C

Tags: c, architecture

My program answers on incoming messages and do some logic based on ID`s and data included in messages.
I have a different function for each ID.
The project is pure C.

To make the code easy to work with I have adjusted all functions to the same style (same return and parameters).
I also want to evade the long switch-case constructions and make code easier to edit later, so I have created the following function:

```
AnswerStruct IDHandler(Request Message)
{
    struct AnswerStruct ANS;
    SIDHandler = IDfunctions[Message.ID];
    ANS = SIDHandler(Message);
    return ANS;
}
```

AnswerStruct is struct for answer messages.
Request is struct for incoming messages.
IDfunctions is array of pointers to functions which looks like this -

```
AnswerStruct func1(Request);
AnswerStruct func4(Request);
...

typedef AnswerStruct(*f)(Request);
AnswerStruct (*SIDHandler)(Request);

static f IDfunctions[IDMax] = {0, *func1, 0, 0, *func4, ...};
```

Function pointers placed in the array cells equal to their id`s, for example:
func1 related to message with ID=1.
func4 related to message with ID=4.

I think, that by using this array I make my life much easier.
I can call function which I need in one step (just go to the IDfunctions[ID]).
Also, adding new functions becomes a two step operation (just add function to the IDfunctions and write logic).

I doubt the efficiency of the selected solution, it seems clunky to me.
The question is - Is this a good architecture?
If no, how can I edit my solution to make it better?
Thanks.

Comment: Nothing new here, This is the standard way of implementing command line interface.

Comment: You are returning the entire struct which is inefficient for larger structs. You can instead pass the struct to the function by address.

Comment: A data structure full of function pointers is an excellent technique.  When you have lots of these functions, you're right, looking up a function pointer by ID, then calling it, is much cleaner than a long if/else chain. (*That* would be clunky!)

Comment: Hi, this question would be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com, Stack Overflow is for programming questions about a specific problem. Some quick suggestions: 1) `IDfunctions` should be `const static` if you're not going to change it. 2) returning structs by value is generally inefficient if the struct is large (but if it isn't large, then avoiding `malloc` is a good thing), 3) `f` is a poor name for a function pointer typedef. 4) Add error-checking to make sure you are within array bounds and that the func. pointer is not null.

Comment: @Groo Thanks for tips. It`s my 1st question, I will read the guide again.

Comment: @Groo No, it is not a good fit for the Code Review site, because that site requires complete, working examples. Whereas SO wants the minimal code needed to reproduce. This question as it stands, is on-topic on SO but off-topic on CR.

Comment: @Lundin: I am pretty sure I've seen dozens of questions asking for "architecture suggestions" being closed for being "opinion based". This one is also incomplete since it doesn't compile, and it's hard to give a concrete suggestion about passing these structs around by value without knowing their size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I doubt the efficiency of the selected solution, it seems clunky to
>   me.

It can be less efficient to call a function via a function pointer than to call it directly by name, because the former denies the compiler any opportunity to optimize the call. But you have to consider whether that actually matters.  In a system that dispatches function calls based on messages received from an external source, the I/O involved in receiving the messages is likely to be much more expensive than the indirect function calls, so the difference in call performance is unlikely to be significant.

On the other hand, your approach affords simpler logic and many fewer lines of code, which is a different and potentially more valuable kind of efficiency.

> The question is - Is this a good architecture?

The general approach is perfectly good, and I don't see much to complain about in the implementation sketch provided.

Personally, I would declare array `IDFunctions` to be `const` (supposing, of course, that you don't intend to replace any of its members after their initialization), but that's a minor safety / performance detail, where again the performance dimension is probably irrelevant.